# How to pass function through props of Redirect in "to" object. Getting DataCloneError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Can put all sorts of data types in state part of "to" JSON attribute which is how you pass props through a Redirect statement with React-Router v4, except for functions. They cause an error.

I can send the function as it's own attribute outside of state section of "to" JSON but causes error upon refresh, because function becomes undefined.

```
if (this.state.redirect)
                return <Redirect
                    to={{
                        pathname: "/sheets",
                        state: {
                            sandboxObj: this.sandboxObj,
                            // function is refreshUserSandboxes
                            refreshUserSandboxes: this.props.refreshUserSandboxes,
                        },

                    }} />;
```

Error:

```
DataCloneError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': function () {
            fetch(window.hostName + 'wali_rest/getUserSandboxes', {
                method: 'GET'...<omitted>... } could not be cloned.
```